# How soon do I need to submit the reference letters? (TT job)

Tags: united-states, recommendation-letter

I'm applying for tenure-track positions for the first time (STEM). One of the schools (School A) contacted me today, saying the committee would like to see my reference letters. The application deadline for School A was only ten days ago. They did not ask for the letters up front, and I did not have a phone interview with them. So this is quite unexpected.

I contacted my references only last week, told them I am applying for the TT jobs. All of my references already told me that they could write my letters by the first week of December.

Would it be too late if I submit the letters to School A in early December? It's not easy for me to ask the references to write the letters sooner.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not that odd to request letters before a phone interview.  The search committee can do whatever they want.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Thanks... but how soon do they usually want to see the letter after the request? Does the committee expect the applicants to have the letters on their hands even though the job ad didn't ask for it? :(

Comment: The only people who know the answer are the committee at School A.  It is reasonable to ask them.

Answer (score 2):

"Dear School A Professor,

Thank you very much for your interest.

My references told me in advance that they'd be able to finish my letters by the first week of December. Will this be enough time, or shall I ask them if they can finish sooner?

Thanks, eggfry"

Comment: Yes, and while the time frame may be unknown, there is certainly some leeway. The committee isn't going to make decisions on the deadline day. And the better you look otherwise, the longer they may be willing to wait. Conversely...